# Not able to create a distribution certificate on Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios

[image: Please see the issue screenshot here]

The add certificate(+) takes me to the above screenshot page and am able to create only development certificate.
I have Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority installed in my Keychain.

Comment: What type of developer account you are using? Might be there are issues with permissions

Comment: It's a team developer account.I have been added to this account by a second person.

Comment: You are not authorized to create distribution  that check with that second person who gave you the access

Comment: @Vinodh Doesn't developer account provide permission to everyone on the account?Thanks for your reply.

Comment: By default apple account provide it . But Team manager can  restrict that thing to stop publishing the app without his knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given rights of team member.As per apple documents you dont have proper rights to create a distribution ceritficates. Check the below link

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: .Thanks bro :).I will inform the other team member.